# KeyError: 'plotly_domain' when using plotly to do scatter plot in python

Tags: python, plot, plotly, keyerror

I'm using plotly to do scatter plot. The graph is generated on my account but the terminal still reports an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "IEORE4709HW1.py", line 106, in <module>
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-scatter')
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.py", line 175, in iplot
return tools.embed(url, **embed_options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/plotly/tools.py", line 412, in embed
!= session.get_session_config()['plotly_domain']):
KeyError: 'plotly_domain'
```

My code is:

```
import urllib2
import numpy as np

import plotly.plotly as py
py.sign_in('halblooline', 'j90503v8gq')
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

N = 1000
random_x = np.random.randn(N)
random_y = np.random.randn(N)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'markers'
)

data = [trace]

# Plot and embed in ipython notebook!
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-scatter')

# or plot with: plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='basic-line')
```

Any one could help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: are you doing this within an ipython notebook? if not, use the `plot()` command as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 60):

use py.plot instead of py.iplot. Have a try.

Comment: This works splendidly. `iplot` works with a Jupyter notebook (previously IPython notebook).